# Delivering Files from AWS Kinesis Firehose to a Specific S3 Folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

**Problem Context**:
I have an AWS Kinesis Firehose delivery stream setup.
I also have an S3 bucket setup.
Within my S3 bucket I have a folder, lets call it: "folderX/".

Currently, it just sends it to a premade folder labeled "2021/" because the default scheme is to send to a folder corresponding to the current date/time.

**Question:**
I want my Firehose delivery stream to send files into *that specific folder*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Backup S3 bucket prefix` in S3 Destination configuration is the spot to set a prefix.

From the [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-s3) for Backup S3 bucket prefix:

> To use the default prefix for Amazon S3 objects, leave this option
> blank. Kinesis Data Firehose automatically uses a prefix in
> "YYYY/MM/dd/HH" UTC time format for delivered Amazon S3 objects. You
> can add to the start of this prefix

[image]

Couple more examples:

To get `folderX/2021/3/17` we can use `folderX/!{timestamp:YYYY}/!{timestamp:MM}/!{timestamp:dd}/`

To get `folderX/year=2021/month=3/day=17/hour=5/` we can use `folderX/year=!{timestamp:YYYY}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:HH}/`

Comment: Hmm I tried that but it does not seem to be working. If a folder was nested within another, would it simply follow this pattern? E.g. rather than folderX/ would it be "folderX/folderY/" ?

Comment: sorry. I missed asking something. what is the source of your firehose, is it Kinesis stream or something else?

Comment: My firehose delivery stream is ingesting/consuming data from a kafka instance via the AWS kafka-kinesis connector

Comment: k. so, you have bunch of documents coming in to firehose and you just want to deliver them to a folder called `folderX/` correct? I have used this `year=!{timestamp:YYYY}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:HH}/`  it basically prefixes all s3 objects with this which places them in  `year=2021/month=3/day=17/hour=5/mydoc.json`.  similarly if you add folderX/ it should place all the documents in that folder.

Comment: I see. So what would the complete prefix field look like? 

Would it be: `folderX/year=!{timestamp:YYYY}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:HH}/`?

Comment: so, if you just folderX/ , it should place them in folderX/ , nothing else is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230058/discussion-between-prithvi-boinpally-and-balu-vyamajala).